# iOS get UITextField text in a thread ,that was show '_WebThreadLockFromAnyThread'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitextfield, nsthread

I want to get text of `UITextField` in a thread.

```
IBOutlet UITextField *textSearchBar;

{ 
   NSThread* thread ......init:@selector(test)....
   [thread start]
}

-(void)test   
{
    NSString* str = textSearchBar.text;//here to show  '_WebThreadLockFromAnyThread'
}
```

i know i can use the code like this to fix it, but i do not want to use this way

```
{ 
   NSThread* thread ......init:@selector(test)..withObject:textSearchBar.text];....
   [thread start]
}

-(void)test:(NSString*)textStr
{
    NSString* str = textStr;
}
```

so anyone knows any other way to get text from `UITextField` without '_WebThreadLockFromAnyThread'

Answer (score 2):

If you are targeting the devices with iOS4.0 and above, then you could use blocks. More info on that : [Grand Central Dispatch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxGettingStarted.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH7-SW1).

[Working with blocks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH8-SW1)

Comment: Agreed, this is the way to join the 21st century.

Comment: could you post some code?i had see. but I was no idea to implements it.thanks very much.

Answer (score -1):

There is only one answer:  Access the UITextView on the main thread.

Comment: yes,i kown it .beacause i need do other things in thread,so i need got text frist,so could you post some code to fix this question?

Comment: You already did, that is the correct way to do it.  I don't know any other way unless you want to use `performSelectorOnMainThread` to get the text

Comment: - (void)performSelectorOnMainThread:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)arg waitUntilDone:(BOOL)wait; the function can not get return value.and if  i definition a variable to get it,the thread may not got.

Comment: Then you need to do it the way you described whether you "want to" or not.